# Sharing docker container

Tags: docker

I've multiple docker containers that have been modified via file system updates. These updates are not represented via changes to the `dockerFile`

This is pseudo code for process  :

```
docker pull image
docker run image
docker exec -it <image_id> bash
'make changes to running docker container image
exit running docker container
docker commit <new container name>
```

To save the container I can use `docker save...` and a local copy of container is saved. Can the be pushed to the registry ? Or is registry just for images and not containers ?

Is the single method of sharing a custom docker container to export it as .tar file and then re-import on other machine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never share containers, you always share images. The `docker commit` command that you've already used **does not save a container**, it creates **a new image from that container's file system** ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)):

> **Create a new image** from a container’s changes
>
> **Usage**
>
> ```
> docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
> ```

You can treat an image created by `docker commit` like you would any other image (create new containers from it, push it to registries, etc.).
Simply create a new image by committing an existing container, and you can push that image anywhere you want:

```
$ docker commit <some-running-container> yourusername/new-image
$ docker push yourusername/new-image
```

If you do not want to use a registry, use the `docker save` command to export an existing image into a file, and the `docker load` command to import the image again.

```
$ docker commit <some-running-container> yourusername/new-image
$ docker save yourusername/new-image > new-image.tar
$ # On another machine:
$ docker load < new-image.tar
```

Comment: thanks, I incorrectly assumed that since docker containers are typically > 1GB then then pushing containers with minor modifications to existing containers is deemed uneconomical and therefore unsupported. This assumption led me to believe that committing a docker container to dockerHub is via the dockerFile only.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is any registry exists for sharing containers. Even if there is, it would be against philosophy of docker. I cant think of a use-case where sharing images would fail but containers will succeed. Images are meant to be shared (platform independent) and containers (platform specific) will be created from those images.